# Kendo UI Toolbar widget and empty DropDownList

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, datasource, toolbar

Lets say I have Kendo Ui toolbar widget with some inputs. Toolbar has dropdownlist and button. By button click user can remove selected items from dropdownlist.

After every remove operation, dropdownlist datasource is read again from the controller. Dropdownlist is refreshed nicely and everything works great as far I remove last item. When controller returns empty array, dropdown is broken.

[image: Everything is so far good]

[image: Here dataSource is empty]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
        items: [
            { template: "<label>Demo:</label>" },
            { template: "<input id='my-drop-down' style='width: 150px;' />" }
        ]
    });

    var myDropDown = $("#my-drop-down").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select My Value",
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: [
            /*
            { text: "Value 1", value: 1 },
            { text: "Value 2", value: 2 },
            { text: "Value 3", value: 3 },
            { text: "Value 4", value: 4 },
            { text: "Value 5", value: 5 },
            */
        ]
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
});
```

Prepared small jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jr8mnnxL/15/)

Comment: If there are no options, what do expect to see (visually)? Did you try leaving an element with text empty and disabling it?

Comment: Good point. At least I expect the widget would look like a dropdownlist, not like the skeleton of it.

Comment: Is this acceptable http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jr8mnnxL/16/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible options:

1. Define a style that controls the `min-height` of the element.
2. Do not remove the latest element and leave an element but mark it as disabled.

Solution 1: Simply define the following style:

```
#toolbar .k-dropdown-wrap {
    min-height: 2em;
}
```

You can see this approach here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jr8mnnxL/19/

Solution 2: Do not remove the latest element but disabling the dropdown:

```
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [
        { template: "<label>Demo:</label>" },
        { template: "<input id='my-drop-down' style='width: 150px; min-height: ' />" }
    ]
});

var myDropDown = $("#my-drop-down").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: "Select My Value",
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "Fake", value: -1 }
        /*
        { text: "Value 1", value: 1 },
        { text: "Value 2", value: 2 },
        { text: "Value 3", value: 3 },
        { text: "Value 4", value: 4 },
        { text: "Value 5", value: 5 },
        */
    ]
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
myDropDown.enable(false);
```

Where I've create an element with `text` set to `fake` but it doesn't matter since the control is enabled / disabled using `myDropDown.enable(true);` / `myDropDown.enable(false);`

You can see this approach here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jr8mnnxL/16/